# JQuery Live Search Bar with Delimiter

Tags: jquery, filtering, delimiter, searchbar, livesearch

I have a search bar on my page that uses JQuery to filter my gridview. I can't figure out how to have it filter on multiple values; using a delimiter to determine the different values.

So if I put in the search bar: Dog, Blue
It would recognize the coma as a delimiter and first filter the table and hide any rows that don't contain Dog and then also hide any rows that don't contain Blue.

Here's my code for what I have now only being able to enter one word.

```
       //Filter Grid logic
       $("tbody").attr('class', 'searchable');
       $('input.filter').on('keyup', function () {
           var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');

           $('.searchable tr').hide();
           $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
               return rex.test($(this).text());
           }).show();

           //Always show the Header row
           $('tr.GridViewHeader').show();
       });
   });
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy that might sound convoluted, but works for me the last time I checked: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/mWK2F/

1. Parse the value from the `<input>` by remove all trailing/leading spaces `^\s*|\s*$`, and then splitting it along `,` while making concessions that perhaps whitespace might be present before/after the comma (therefore using `\s*,\s*`
2. Construct 'RegExp' object by joining the array with `|`, which is the **OR** operator in regex.

Here is your modified script

```
//Filter Grid logic
$("tbody").attr('class', 'searchable');
$('input.filter').on('keyup', function () {
    // Construct array of search text
    var searchtext = $(this).val().replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'').split(/\s*,\s*/),
        // Construct new RegExp object
        rex = new RegExp(searchtext.join('|'),'i');

    $('.searchable tr').hide();
    $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();

    //Always show the Header row
    $('tr.GridViewHeader').show();
});
```

However, if you want to match **full** words, you will need to use word boundaries, `\b`. Remember to escape the backslash, so we use `\\b` instead. Code was inspired after seeing a similar answer here: [javascript match against array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219960/javascript-match-against-array)

```
rex = new RegExp('\\b'+searchtext.join('\\b|\\b')+'\\b','i');
```

Comment: This is great!!! It does work in your jfiddle example, but when I put it in my site, it doesn't do anything at all? Playing with it now to try and figure out why, any ideas?

Comment: What does the browser console say? Did you ensure that the code is executed on DOM ready? Also note that there is an extraneous `});` in your code - might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the above answer a bit to get it to do 'AND' here's the solution:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       //Filter Grid logic
       $("tbody").attr('class', 'searchable');
       $('input.filter').on('keyup', function () {
           // Construct array of search text
           var searchtext = $(this).val().split(' ');
           // Construct new RegExp object
           var rex = new RegExp('(?=.*' + searchtext.join(')(?=.*') + ').*', 'ig');

           $('.searchable tr').hide();
           $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
               return $(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ").match(rex)
           }).show();

           //Always show the Header row
           $('tr.GridViewHeader').show();
       });
```

});